# Why cant my code continue what i want it to?

Tags: python

```py
import playsound
import winsound
import time
import colorama
from colorama import init
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
from playsound import playsound

game_running = True
playsound('Sounds/Start_Game.mp3', False)
time.sleep(10)
print('Welcome, User, to Attack and Conquer')
time.sleep(2)
print('What would be the name of this glorious adventurer?: ')
name = (Fore.LIGHTGREEN_EX + input() + Fore.RESET)

time.sleep(3)
print('Welcome ' + name + ", We have long awaited to train such a mighty warrior.")
time.sleep(2)
print(
    name + ', Welcome to Fish Ville, here we train pure donkeys until they become ready for warfare. Did you know that we have trained mighty warriors like Alexander the Great?')
time.sleep(2)
print(
    'You will have 2 options in a battle, one of them is to attack the enemy, and the other one is to heal yourself. Understand?')
time.sleep(2)
answer1 = input()
print("Nice you're ready for battle!")
time.sleep(2)
print("Lets give you a enemy for now!")
time.sleep(2)

player = {'name': name, 'attack': 10, 'heal': 15, 'health': 100}
monsterdummy = {'name': "Dummy", 'attack': 0, 'health': 10}
print("This monster is called " + monsterdummy['name'] + "!")
time.sleep(2)
print("He doesn't deal any damage, and he has a health value of only 10!")
time.sleep(2)
print("Remember, enemies grow stronger over time, some have a heal option, others dont!")
time.sleep(2)
print("Here you Go!")
time.sleep(2)
print("What do you want to do now " + name + "?")
time.sleep(2)
print('1) Attack ' + monsterdummy['name'] + "!")
player_choice = input()
if player_choice == '1':
    monsterdummy['health'] = monsterdummy['health'] - player['attack']
    print("You Damaged " + monsterdummy['name'] + "!")
    print("Dummy is now on " + "0")
    if monsterdummy['health'] <= 0:
        print("Nice, you defeated " + monsterdummy['name'] + " !")
        wonDummy = 1
    else:
        player['health'] = player['health'] - monsterdummy['attack']
        print(monsterdummy[name] + " has damaged you!")
        if player['health'] <= 0:
            print("You Died!")
            game_running == False
            print("1) Restart")
            player_choicedeath = input()
            if player_choicedeath == '1':
                game_running == True
        game_running == False
else:
    print("Invalid Input, Try Again!")


class Access(object):
    pass


if wonDummy == 1:
    print("Now that you have defeated " + monsterdummy[
        'name'] + " you proved that you are ready for more fierce and epic battles!")
    time.sleep(2)
    trainer_name = "Natalie"
    print("I by the way, am " + trainer_name + ", i will be your trainer throughout the entire game!")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("Please accept this med-kit and sword that i will give you now")
    time.sleep(5)
    print("There you Go!")
    time.sleep(2)
    print(Fore.CYAN + "Achievement Acquired: Equip Yourself!")

    playsound('Sounds\ACS.wav')

    time.sleep(2)
    stone_sword = 20
    medkit = 10
    player['attack'] = player['attack'] + stone_sword
    print("Woah! This sword looks awesome!")
    time.sleep(2)
    player['heal'] = player['heal'] + medkit
    print("Yes! this will sure be helpful later on!")
    time.sleep(4)
    print(trainer_name + ": Great, you now you will have the option to heal yourself in battle!")
    time.sleep(4)
    print("Now you can choose where you want to go!")
    time.sleep(4)
    print("Where do you want to go now " + name)
    print("1) Sparta")

    lockedTroy = 1
    lockedTroy = True
    if lockedTroy == True:
        print(Fore.RED + Back.BLACK + "2) Troy Locked")
    # Not Yet Complete

    lockedRome = 1
    lockedRome = True
    if lockedRome == True:
        print(Back.BLACK + "3) Rome " + Fore.RED + " Locked")
    # Not Yet Complete

    lockedShop = 1
    lockedShop = True
    if lockedShop == True:
        print(Back.BLACK + "4) Shop " + Fore.RED + " Locked")
    # Not Yet Complete

    player_choice1 = input()
    if player_choice1 == '1':
        time.sleep(2)
        playsound('Sounds\Walk.wav')
        time.sleep(2)
        print("You Have Entered Rome")
        print(Fore.CYAN + "Achievement Acquired: Entering Rome!")
        playsound("Sounds\ACS.wav ")
        print(Fore.BLUE + Back.BLACK + "Leonidas has " + Fore.GREEN + " CHALLENGED " + Fore.BLUE + " you to a battle!")
        time.sleep(2)
        print(
            Fore.BLUE + Back.BLACK + "Leonidas : " + Fore.CYAN + "Why have you entered my city without my permission!")
        time.sleep(2)
        print(Fore.BLUE + Back.BLACK + "Leonidas : " + Fore.CYAN + "Now you shall PAY for this!")
        time.sleep(2)
        print(
            Fore.CYAN + "Achievent Acquired: " + Fore.LIGHTGREEN_EX + "(" + Fore.MAGENTA + "RARE" + Fore.LIGHTGREEN_EX + ")" + Fore.LIGHTBLUE_EX + " Challenged!")
        time.sleep(3)
        print(Fore.YELLOW + Back.MAGENTA + "You have 24 Hours until Leonidas fights you!")
        time.sleep(1)
        print(Fore.YELLOW + Back.MAGENTA + "Do what you can to help yourself!")
        time.sleep(2)
        Bed = False
        print("What do you want to do now " + name)
        print("1) Enter Spartan Shop")
        print("2) Visit Stranger")
        if Bed != False:
            print("3) Sleep")
        player_choice2 = input()
        if player_choice2 == '1':
            print("You have entered the shop but was kicked because Leonidas has blocked you from entering")
        elif player_choice2 == '2':
            print("Seems like you have been challenged by Leonidas!")
            time.sleep(2)
            print("I'll give you some coins and the access to my hotel for you to sleep.")
            time.sleep(3)
            print("But on one condition, if you win, you will give me that stone sword!")
            time.sleep(2)
            print("Tell me " + Fore.GREEN + "Yes " + Fore.RED + "No" + Fore.WHITE + "!")
            player_choice3 = input()
            if player_choice3 == 'Yes':
                Access = 10
            elif player_choice == 'No':
                print(Fore.RED + Back.LIGHTBLACK_EX + "YOU DIED!")
                game_running = False
            else:
                print("Invalid Input, Try Again")
        elif player_choice2 == '3':
            if not Bed:
                print("You Cannot Do This now, you do not have a bed to sleep")

                if str(Access) == int(10):
                    print("You have slept!")
                    print("24 Hours have now past! Enter the Battlefield!")
                    print(
                        Fore.BLUE + Back.BLACK + "Leonidas: " + Fore.CYAN + Style.BRIGHT + "You have now entered my battlefield, you cannot escape, the only was is to " + Style.DIM + "DIE")
                    print(Fore.WHITE + Back.BLACK + name + ": There is a DIFFERENT way my friend, what if you die?")
                    playsound('Sounds\Leonidas_Attack.mp3')
                    print(trainer_name + ": Oh No! you have made Leonidas mad!")
                    Leonidas = {'health': 250, 'attack': 20}
                    player['health'] = player['health'] - Leonidas['attack']
                    print(trainer_name + ": You have now been attack by Leonidas and now have" + player['health'])
                    print(trainer_name + ": What do you want to do now?")
                    print("1) Attack " + Leonidas['name'])
                    print("2) Heal Yourself")

                    while Leonidas['health'] > 0:
                        player_choice4 = input()
                        if player_choice4 == '1':
                            Leonidas['health'] = Leonidas['health'] - player['attack']
                    if Leonidas['health'] < 0:

                        print("You Have Defeated Leonidas")
                        wonLeonidas = True
                    elif Leonidas['health'] >= 0:

                        player['health'] = player['health'] - Leonidas['attack']
                        print("Your health is now on " + player['health'])
                        playsound("Sounds\Leonidas_Attack.mp3")
                        print("Leonidas health is now on" + Leonidas['health'])

            if player_choice4 == '2':
                player['health'] = player['health'] + player['heal']
                if Leonidas['health'] <= 0:
                    print("You Have Defeated Leonidas")
                    wonLeonidas = True
                elif Leonidas['health'] >= 0:
                    player['health'] = player['health'] - Leonidas['attack']
                    playsound("Sounds\Leonidas_Attack.mp3")
```

The Output I get doesn't have an Error, but my code doesn't continue after the `player_choice3` variable input is "Yes", when I input "Yes", I get Process Finished with exit code 0.
Not "You Have Slept"...and so on.
Can someone help me?
What I want to do is when I input "Yes" on line 160,( or where I enter something for the variable `player_choice3`), to print Everything after line 172( or the line that says `if str(Access) == int(10)`).

Comment: At most one of `player_choice2 == '2' `and `player_choice2 == '3'` branches will be taken.

Answer (score 0):

In line number 149 You enter a value for `player_choice2`this Value has to be "2" to reach Line 160, where you can enter a value for `player_choice3`. Now in the given case, that `player_choice2=="2"` and `player_choice3=='Yes'` You would skip the `elif`-statements in Line 163 and 166, because of the `else` part in the `elif` (elif = else if). So then you are in Line 168. And there is another `elif`, which again gets skipped because the `if` in Line 152 is true, so your program ends, because there is no executable code left.

You can fix that by adding 
     `player_choice2 = 3`
after the 
     `Access = 10` 
in Line 162, and change the `elif` in line 168 to an `if`-statement. Then it should work

Then it should look somewhat like this:

```
elif player_choice2 == '2':
    print("Seems like you have been challenged by Leonidas")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("I'll give you some coins and the access to my hotel for you to sleep.")
    time.sleep(3)
    print("But on one condition, if you win, you will give me that stone sword!")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("Tell me " + Fore.GREEN + "Yes " + Fore.RED + "No" + Fore.WHITE + "!")
    player_choice3 = input()
    if player_choice3 == 'Yes':
        Access = 10
        player_choice2 = "3"
    elif player_choice == 'No':
        print(Fore.RED + Back.LIGHTBLACK_EX + "YOU DIED!")
        game_running = False
    else:
        print("Invalid Input, Try Again")
if player_choice2 == '3':
    if not Bed:
        print("You Cannot Do This now, you do not have a bed to sleep")

        if str(Access) == int(10):
            print("You have slept!")
...
```

Comment: Im Sorry but im confused about your statement, i didnt type player_choice2 = 2, but player_choice2 == '2'. Which means that if the input is 2 then do the following, not a integer but an input(). Which i suppose means that this wont work.
I have tried your fix, but the code stops anyway before reaching the code in line 174.
If you can help me or thing im wrong point me please. It's my first ever code, and im self-taught "student" in the age of 11. :P

Comment: I'm not really sure if I understand what your problem is, but I fixed some typo-issues in my answer, maybe now your problem is solved, otherwise please clarify your problem

Comment: You say it stops way earlier, where exactly does it stop, and why, do you have an error message, or can you debug your code and see where the problem is?